# Can't access newly created plone site on Plone 5.0.5 on OS X 10.11.6

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

After successful(?) new install of Plone 5.0.5 on OSX 10.11.6. I can run plone in the foreground for development purposes. I can then create a plone site. However, when I try to access the site the newly created site plone crashes with the following in the console. Is there a workaround to this?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
tricorder: [~/Plone/zinstance] % ~/Plone/zinstance/bin/plonectl fg
instance: 2016-08-19 13:31:30 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Fri Aug 19 13:31:30 2016
        Hostname: 0.0.0.0
        Port: 8080
2016-08-19 13:31:31 INFO DocFinderTab Applied patch version 1.0.5.
/Users/lholton/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.dexterity-2.3.1-py2.7.egg/plone/app/dexterity/__init__.py:12: DeprecationWarning: Name clash, now use '_' as usal. Will be removed in Plone 5.2
  DeprecationWarning)
/Users/lholton/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.multilingual-4.0.2-py2.7.egg/plone/app/multilingual/browser/migrator.py:11: DeprecationWarning: LanguageRootFolder: LanguageRootFolders should be migrate to DexterityContainers
  from plone.app.multilingual.content.lrf import LanguageRootFolder
2016-08-19 13:31:34 INFO Plone OpenID system packages not installed, OpenID support not available
2016-08-19 13:31:36 INFO Zope Ready to handle requests
2016-08-19 13:31:52 INFO plone.app.theming.policy local cache invalidated on thread 123145311330304
2016-08-19 13:31:52 INFO plone.app.theming.policy initializing local cache on thread 123145311330304 for http://localhost:8080/gmesaz::barceloneta
/Users/lholton/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.deprecation-3.4.1-py2.7.egg/zope/deprecation/deprecation.py:79: DeprecationWarning: isDefaultPage is deprecated. Import from Products.CMFPlone.defaultpage instead
  name)
/Users/lholton/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/five.pt-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/five/pt/expressions.py:161: DeprecationWarning: showEditableBorder is renamed to showToolbar
  return base()
python(10738,0x70000089a000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fc94f0c6d78: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Comment: Are you using the Python 2.7 that's shipped with OS X? Or, did you build another or inherit one from ports or some other software package? Did you use the XCode build tools? Or something else? This is a very low level error that suggests some problem in the Python or build tools.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was an issue with my MacPorts installation which had not been updated for the latest OSX.

To resolve the issue I followed instructions on Migrating a MacPorts Installation located at: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration